# proxy server in go using existing net.Conn

Tags: go, proxy

yoyo
i need help writing a proxy server in go (doesn't matter if it's http or other types) that uses an existing net.Conn connection which the proxy redirect every message received into the existing net.Conn

if this is not possible is it possible to send a http request with an existing net.Conn instead of using http.Client or other tools ?
n

i'm not really good at go plz send help

Edit0:
the underlying net.Conn that should be used as a proxy come from snowflake, here's the providing code

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    sf "git.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/snowflake.git/v2/client/lib"
)

func main() {

    config := sf.ClientConfig{
        BrokerURL:   "https://snowflake-broker.torproject.net.global.prod.fastly.net/",
        FrontDomain: "cdn.sstatic.net",
        ICEAddresses: []string{
            "stun:stun.voip.blackberry.com:3478",
            "stun:stun.stunprotocol.org:3478",
            "stun:stun.altar.com.pl:3478",
            "stun:stun.antisip.com:3478",
            "stun:stun.bluesip.net:3478",
            "stun:stun.dus.net:3478",
            "stun:stun.epygi.com:3478",
            "stun:stun.sonetel.com:3478",
            "stun:stun.sonetel.net:3478",
            "stun:stun.uls.co.za:3478",
            "stun:stun.voipgate.com:3478",
            "stun:stun.voys.nl:3478"},
        Max: 1,
    }
    transport, err := sf.NewSnowflakeClient(config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to start snowflake transport: ", err)
    }

    // transport implements the ClientFactory interface and returns a net.Conn
    conn, err := transport.Dial()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("dial error: %s", err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    //--
    // use conn here to make a proxy and skip the snowstorm closed beta
    for {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, brother

Here is a simple example program

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
    "net/http"
)

func handleClient(conn net.Conn) {
    defer conn.Close()

    request, err := http.ReadRequest(bufio.NewReader(conn))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading request:", err)
        return
    }

     //Modify the request as needed

    response, err := http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(request)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error sending request:", err)
        return
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    response.Write(conn)
}

func main() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error starting proxy server:", err)
        return
    }
    defer listener.Close()

    fmt.Println("Proxy server is running on port 8080")

    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting connection:", err)
            continue
        }
        go handleClient(conn)
    }
}
```

we first created a proxy server that listens on port 8080. Then, we use the Accept method to accept client connections and initiate an independent goroutine on each connection to process the request.

If you are not good at Go, you may need to learn more basic knowledge. Go is a great language, I hope you will like it.

If there are any questions in my answer, please raise them with me

Comment: thank bro but i need to use an existing net.Conn to do the actual fetching from the web like 
response, err := http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(request)
when you do this i need this to be done with a net.Conn that comes from somewhere else